# Q:data filtrate by listin a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have a dataframe named df,which contains serveral columns. One columns named A. And I have a list named b,which contains a part of data in column A. Now I want to filtrate the dataframe df,with column A only consists of the elements in list b.
I've used the following code:

```
for i in b:
    df = df[df.A == i]
```

But the dataframe df becomes empty.
So how to filtrate the dataframe?
thx

Comment: If not dupe, please add sample data and desired output and question will be reopened ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df[df.A.isin(b)]
```